# trying to round robin a set of devices against set of criteria

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I have 2 lists, both of which aren't fixed in len.

```
list1 = ["John", "bruce", "William"]
list2 = ["lindt", "reese", "snickers", "chocolate", "Milkyway", "Cadbury", "Candy"]
```

I want to distribute the candy amongst the members in list1 so that end result would look something like

```
John: "lindt","chocolate","candy"
Bruce: "reese","Mlikyway"
Will: "Snickers","Cadbury"
```

I tried using `cycle` and `zip` from `itertools` but all I am getting is a tuple with something like

```
list1 = ["John","bruce","William"]
list2 = ["lindt","reese","snickers","chocolate","Milkyway","Cadbury","Candy"]
for i in zip(list2,cycle(list1)):
    print(i)
```

### Output

```
('lindt', 'John')
('reese', 'bruce')
('snickers', 'William')
('chocolate', 'John')
('Milkyway', 'bruce')
('Cadbury', 'William')
('Candy', 'John')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use a dictionary:

```
kids = {}
```

all members from list1 become a list in your dictionary:

```
for i in list1: kids[i] = []
```

then use zip and cycle to assign each kid their candy:

```
for i in zip(list2,cycle(list1)): kids[i[1]].append(i[0])
# kids[i[1]] represents the kids's name since it's at index 1 in the tuple
# i[0] represents the candy that is associated to the kid.
```

Result:

```
>>> for i in kids: print(i,':', kids[i])
john : ['lindt', 'chocolate', 'candy']
bruce : ['reese', 'milkyway']
william : ['snickers', 'cadbury']
```

Comment: Thanks Maheux, but i think what i am seeing is that when we are assigning the value to key it overrides it.
I end up getting only the last value.
kids[i[1]] = i[0] ### 
wouldn't this overwrite the previous value and i am not able to find out how do i append to that particular list with explicitly defining it everytime
this is what i get after running it 
John : Candy
bruce : Milkyway
William : Cadbury

Comment: Fixed.. I seem to have written down a part of the code I tested instead of the working code.

Comment: now you have a dictionary where each member of list1 is a list, containing the candy that was distributed from list2 using zip and cycle as in your code

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close but you need a data structure to store these results. Instead of creating a dictionary containing the keys and empty lists you can also use [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
from itertools import cycle

d = dict()
for name, item in zip(cycle(list1), list2):
    d.setdefault(name, []).append(item)

print(d)
# {'John': ['lindt', 'chocolate', 'Candy'],
#  'William': ['snickers', 'Cadbury'],
#  'bruce': ['reese', 'Milkyway']}
```

Instead of `setdefault` you can also use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from itertools import cycle
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for name, item in zip(cycle(list1), list2):
    d[name].append(item)

print(d)
# defaultdict(list,
#             {'John': ['lindt', 'chocolate', 'Candy'],
#              'William': ['snickers', 'Cadbury'],
#              'bruce': ['reese', 'Milkyway']})
```